# How to use Monte Carlo integration on a linear combination of f(x)?

Tags: monte-carlo

Let be $f(x)$ a function which can be expressed as a linear combination of other functions: $$f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)+...+f_n(x)$$ would it be possible to apply Monte Carlo integration to each one of the factors and mix them somehow in order to get the right result of $f(x)$? If it's so, how?

**Example x 1-dimension**: Let's say you want to integrate $f(x)$ between on the interval $[x0,x1]$ using a uniform Monte Carlo estimator:
$$f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$$ $$f_1(x)=ax^2\\f_2(x)=bx+c$$ $$a,b,c\ \ \text{constants}$$

How would you proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key thing underlying many MC methods is that expected values of sums are the sum of the expected values:

E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)

*WHETHER OR NOT X and Y are INDEPENDENT!*

I personally find that kind of amazing.   What this means is you can do pretty much anything (including re-using samples between sum components) are you have a unbiased estimate.

So for your example estimate f1 and f2 separately and then just add the estimates.